# In Memory Web Api returns {data: Array[0]}

Tags: javascript, angular, mocking

I'm trying to get some mocked results for my development environment. I've tried to incorporate [angular-in-memory-web-api](https://github.com/angular/in-memory-web-api) without much success. Here's my code:

app.module.ts:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
    HttpModule,
    ...
    InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(MockEventData, {
      passThruUnknownUrl: true
    })
  ],
  providers: [
    ...
    {
      provide: Http,
      useClass: ExtendedHttpService
    },
    ...
    {
      provide: EventService,
      useFactory: (http: Http, userService: UserService, newEventService: NewEventService, router: Router) => {
        if (environment.production) {
          return new EventService(http, userService, newEventService, router)
        } else {
          return new MockEventService(http, userService, newEventService, router)
        }
      },
      deps: [Http, UserService, NewEventService, Router]
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
```

mock-event.service.ts:

```
@Injectable()
export class MockEventService {

  private imageUploadBatch: Observable<Boolean>[];
  private fakeResponse;

  constructor(
    private http: Http,
    private userService: UserService,
    private newEventService: NewEventService,
    private router: Router,
  ) {

  };

  getEvents(excludedEvents: string[]): Observable<Event[]> {
    return this.http
      .post('api/events', excludedEvents)
      .map((res: Response) => res.json())
      .publishLast().refCount()
      .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Show error.'));
  }
}
```

mock-event-data.ts:

```
import { InMemoryDbService } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';
export class MockEventData implements InMemoryDbService {
  createDb() {
    let events = [
      { id: 1, name: 'Windstorm' },
      { id: 2, name: 'Bombasto' },
      { id: 3, name: 'Magneta' },
      { id: 4, name: 'Tornado' }
    ];
    return { events };
  }
}
```

The code is quite simple. I made it following this guide: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html. However, for whatever reason, the `POST` for /events always returns `{data: Array[0]}`.

Any help provided will be deeply appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`post` method will NOT just retrieve the data to `angular-in-memory-web-api`. Instead it will create the entity accordingly. It's essential and default behavior is to send data to the server same as `put` and `delete`. Of course there will be a response to the post request which is probably the data in `angular-in-memory-web-api` case but remember, this totally depends on the server to response. On the other`get` should be used for the purpose of retrieving data from `angular-in-memory-web-api` as you want.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as it turns out, `POST` seems to not return data in `angular-in-memory-web-api`. I succeeded in retrieving data by using a `GET` request. This isn't ideal, but it'll have to work for now.

If someone has a better answer, please provide it, as it's a bit iffy to commit a mock that doesn't use the original request types.

Thanks!